# Valgrind with Java in Mac

Tags: java, valgrind

I want to use Valgrind to track a JNI memory leak, but Valgrind always crashes if I use it to track java program. I tried other programs like bash, these all worked well.

My OS: MacOs High Sierra Version 10.13.2

Install Valgrind by:

```
brew install --HEAD valgrind
```

Execute command:

```
valgrind java -h
```

Error Information:

> valgrind: m_debuginfo/debuginfo.c:452 (void
>   discard_or_archive_DebugInfo(DebugInfo *)): Assertion
>   'is_DebugInfo_active(di)' failed.

Did anyone have this issue before? How do you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

See bug https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=393146
which contains a workaround (but not a real fix).